# Creating a LiveTile Image - Looks Good On Screen - Looks Wrong As LiveTile

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, win-universal-app

I'm drawing some shapes onto the screen on my Windows Universal App and then I'm also trying to save the base UIElement into a file and assign my LiveTile template to use it.

I think I'm close, but something is very wrong.  Here's how it looks on my screen:
[image: How it appears on screen]

And here is how it looks on the Tile:

[image: How it appears on start screen]

The black in the first image is meant to be transparent, and the live tile seems to have a lot of transparent pixels (the light grey is my background image).  I can see lots of yellow and green, so it seems to be correctly creating/finding the file and updating the live tile template.  I just can't get it to look how I intended it to - on my Windows Phone.

However, on my Windows 10 desktop - it looks how I'd expect (only it seems to have lost it's transparency - which I'm happy enough with)
[image: On my desktop]

The Canvas is 150x150.  The live tile template is TileSquare150x150Image.  I'm using a .png file.  I've tried changing the BitmapPixelFormat, manually setting the logicalDpi to use when calling encoder.SetPixelData, and using different BitmapAlphaModes...occasionally these throw exceptions, otherwise it seems to render about the same.

Can anyone nudge me in the right direction?  I thought a Universal App would ensure the same behavior between devices, so I was very surprised to see it behaving so differently between the phone and desktop...but I'm sure I'm just doing something incorrectly.  My code looks like this:

```
var renderBitMap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
await renderBitMap.RenderAsync(_container);

var pixels = await renderBitMap.GetPixelsAsync();            
byte[] myBytes = pixels.ToArray();

var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("ts150.png", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
var logicalDpi = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi;
using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream);
    encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, (uint)options.Size.Width, (uint)options.Size.Height, logicalDpi, logicalDpi, myBytes);

    await encoder.FlushAsync();
}
```

Comment: You should call `SetPixelData()` with renderBitMap.PixelWidth/Height instead of those you get from that `options` variable. I doubt they're the same. `RenderAsync()` scales the image based on the value of `DisplayInformation.RawPixelsPerViewPixel`.

Comment: @yasen - Thank you.  That completely solved my issue.  If you want to post this as an answer - I'd accept it.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're rendering a control using `RenderTargetBitmap`, the image is automatically scaled by [`DisplayInformation.RawPixelsPerViewPixel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.graphics.display.displayinformation.rawpixelsperviewpixel.aspx) (even if you specify width and height in the `RenderAsync()` call).

For this reason, you should always use the `PixelWidth` and `PixelHeight` properties of the `RenderTargetBitmap` to determine the actual size of the image that was rendered.

The problem in the question is that `options.Size.Width` and `options.Size.Height` are not the same as the values from the `RenderTargetBitmap`, and so the pixel data and the size of the image passed to the encoder do not match.